# Getting a Failed prop type: The prop `children` when using material ui modal

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I get in dev tools:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(ModalUnstyled)`, but its value is `undefined`.
    at ModalUnstyled (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:97550:5)
    at Modal (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:83533:82)
    at div
    at Row (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:330420:5)
    at TeamManagement (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:11791:69)
    at Route (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:266394:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:266596:29)
    at div
    at Router (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:266013:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:265634:35)
    at div
    at DashboardWrap (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:658:69)
    at CookiesProvider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:207010:24)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:263015:5)
    at App
```

When attempting to use a `Modal` from material ui in react js

```
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
```

And this what is failing:

```
  const childProps = {};
  if (children.props.tabIndex === undefined) {
    childProps.tabIndex = '-1';
  }
```

with the message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')`

Comment: Could you add more context/code of where this is happening?

Comment: it is happening just using a plain Modal: just rendering this through a component causes the error:  `<Modal open={true}> </Modal>`

Comment: I think it is because `children` is an array of elements so you should use an index to find the `child` you want the `tabIndex` from

Comment: the `tabIndex` thing is inside code from the library, so I can't do anything with it